# Exporting animation to FBX

Tags: animation, export, .fbx

I have a problem with exporting animation from Blender to FBX. After I export to fbx, I open fbx file with FBX Review and can not see any animation. When I import fbx back to blender there is no previous animation and data.
What was my mistake while exporting?
How it can be solved?

My .blend file:
[image]

My export (default) settings:
[image]

Comment: Not sure what is correct way to do this, but I solved my problem by baking all animations: 
 (Select Armature->Object menu in object mode->Animation->Bake Action).

I think my mistake was that I thought FBX supports Blender constraint, but as I understand it don’t. Therefore all animations which are driven by blender constraints will be lost if it exported to FBX.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add some key frame (location, rotation). Then u can export to fBX format [image]

[image]

select the object, curve and bone then export to FBX. It worked for me.

[image]